# e^(jωt) /e^-(jωt), What do these means in terms of coding?

Tags: c, math, exp

What does e<sup>jωt</sup> / e<sup>-jωt</sup> mean in terms of coding?

I know it is **e<sup>jωt</sup> = cos(ωt)+jsin(ωt)**.
But if you have it in terms of an algorithm how do you program it?

[image: part of an algorithm]

Answer (score 1):

There's a special function to raise e to a power, called `exp`.  So you want:

```
exp(j*w*t)
```

Or:

```
exp(-j*w*t)
```

To use this function you'll need to `#include <math.h>`, and when compiling on Linux systems add the `-lm` flag to link the math library.

EDIT:

If `j` is the imaginary unit, you can use the `cexp` function to raise e to a complex power:

```
cexp(I*w*t)
```

You can store the result in a variable of type `double complex` and use the `creal` and `cimag` functions to extract the real and imaginary parts.  Also, you 'll need to  `#include <complex.h>`

Comment: `j` here is the complex number so you can't use the normal `exp` function for that

Answer (score -1):

As you say, **e^(jωt) = cos(ωt)+jsin(ωt)**

While **e^(-jωt) = cos(ωt)-jsin(ωt)** <- sign-change for second term

Therefore,
e^(jωt) / e^(-jωt)

is simply

( cos(ωt)+jsin(ωt) ) / ( cos(ωt)-jsin(ωt) )

You may find the following paper useful. http://web.mit.edu/6.02/www/s2007/lec3.pdf